# modifying original list with each word as lowercase

Tags: python

this function is suppose to take each word in the string list and print them as lowercase, (I am doing this by modifying the original list) but I am getting the error:

> builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
    """takes a list of strings and modifies by replacing each string with lowercase"""
    for word in strings:
        strings[word] = strings[word].lowercase()
    print(strings)

set_lowercase(['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a `for` loop with:

```
for word in strings:
```

you iterate on the elements of `strings`, which are your words. On each loop, `word` becomes one of your words, not its index.

If you need both the word and its index (and you need it here, as you want to update the list in place), you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which will give you on each iteration both the word and the index:

```
def set_lowercase(strings):
        """takes a list of strings and modifies by replacing each string with lowercase"""
        for index, word in enumerate(strings):
            strings[index] = word.lower()


words = ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred'] 
set_lowercase(words)
print(words)
# ['right', 'said', 'fred']
# your original list has been modified in place.
```

Answer (score 1):

**The culprit**:

```
strings[word] = strings[word].lowercase()
```

**The reason**:

```
strings[word]
```

where word is an element in the list, You cannot iterate over a list by its element. Furthermore, there is no such method as `lowercase()` but `lower()`

**The fix**:

```
 for i in range(len(strings)):
        strings[i] = strings[i].lower()
    print(strings)
```

**Alternative**:

You can achieve the same using `list-comprehension`:

```
[x.lower() for x in ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['right', 'said', 'fred']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `strings[word]`, it expects `word` to be the index rather than the actual value you are looking for. 
A better way to achieve this result would be using a list comprehension as follows:

```
upper_case = ['Right', 'SAID', 'Fred']
lower_case = [x.lower() for x in upper_case]
```